# The "+" token button is not showing in the "Tokens Tab" on my "MetaMask'

Tags: metamask

The "+" token button is not showing in the "Tokens Tab" on my "MetaMask'.  It says :There was a problem loading your token balances."  Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To force a retry, click the "sent" tab and then "tokens" again. This error is usually the result of a network error, and should clear up easily.